# BIND - hostname check

Tags: dns, bind

I'm learning DNS. Please give me your advice.

My book tells me that Bind checks names that considered hostnames.
It says Hostnames are in the name fields of A and MX records. Hostnames are also in the data fields of SOA and NS records - yes, I agree.

However, it says that CNAMEs do not have to conform to the host-naming rules because they can point to names that are not hostnames.

I think CNAME has hostname in its data field anyway, does it not ?
Does this mean CNAMEs could be recursive so that CNAME do not have to conform host-naming rules in BIND ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the DNS server that you are adding your CNAMEs to.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record

For example, I have seen a few poorly written DNS servers allow for a CNAME which points back to itself. Other DNS servers like bind require strict naming and formatting for the CNAME entry or it will reject the config. Having said that, there is also and option in bind to disable strict name checking so that it allows more free-form entries.

When using CNAMEs it is best to use RFC standard entries because you rarely know all of the clients that will be consuming the CNAME. If you start using something questionable then you will run into all sorts of weird one-offs that do not work.